# Is there a way to figure out the block machine name?

Tags: blocks

In Drupal 8, is there a way to figure out what current block or view machine name you should use?

For example, with the following code, I noticed that `'machine_name_to_determine'` could change depending on how many times you have used your block.

```
$block_id = 'machine_name_to_determine';
$block_config = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
```

I need a way to retrieve this at run-time. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the blocks by the plugin id. This is the id of a block plugin or for derivatives like a view block (which you probably are looking for as you've mentioned a view machine name) with additional parameters:

```
$plugin_id = 'views_block:' . $view_id . '-' . $display_id;
```

Where `$view_id` is the view machine name which you find in the Views UI and `$display_id` is the display machine name, usually `block_1` for the first block of the view.

Then get all blocks placed for this plugin id and print the block machine names or use the loaded blocks in your code:

```
$blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')
  ->loadByProperties(['plugin' => $plugin_id]);
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
  echo $block->id();
}
```

Add a theme or region to loadByProperties() if needed:

```
['theme' => 'bartik', 'region' => 'header']
```

Comment: Thanks 4k4 for your response and that has actually given me the right nodge to the answer i need.

Answer (score -2):

This is in accordance to the pointer by @4k4

```
$plugin_id = 'bookingsystem_block';
$block_id = $this->getCurrentBlockId($plugin_id);
protected function getCurrentBlockId($plugin_id)
{
    $block_id = NULL;

    $blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')
        ->loadByProperties(['plugin' => $plugin_id]);

    $current_route_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

    foreach ($blocks as $block)
    {
        $visibility = $block->getVisibility();
        $request_path = $visibility['request_path'];
        $request_path_url_arr = explode("\r\n", $request_path['pages']);

        $node_url_arr = array();

        foreach ($request_path_url_arr as $path_alias)
        {
            $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($path_alias);
            if(preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
                $node_url_arr[] = $path;
            }
            else if($path_alias=='<front>') {
                $node_url_arr[] = '/';
            }
        }

        $request_path_url_arr = array_merge($request_path_url_arr,$node_url_arr);

        if(in_array($current_route_path,$request_path_url_arr))
        {
            $block_id = $block->id();
            break;
        }
    }

    return $block_id;
}
```